# Dynamically creating controls based on variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

First off I'm actually a DBA and not a web developer so... what I write will probably look ugly. I am building a website (they asked me if I'd try /shrug) and I have 168 checkboxes that have the same action when checked. But these actions, though the same, are performed on different controls (related to the checkbox). Instead of having a switch statement with 168 conditions can I do something like the following?

```
CheckBox myCB = (CheckBox)(sender);

String mySTR = myCB.ID.ToString();
String myGVstr = “gv” + mySTR.Substring(mySTR.IndexOf(‘cb’) + 1);
String myBTNstr = “btn” + mySTR.Substring(mySTR.IndexOf(‘cb’) + 1);

GridView myGV = myGVstr;
Button myBTN = myBTNstr;

// Do what I need to do with these controls
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really doesn't seem like a plausible thing to do.  Maybe on loading you can place all your controls into a large array?  It would take 1 large section of code to place each control into the array but afterwards you can access them in a similar (more reliable) fashion.

If you insist on doing it this way the 'FindControl' method might be of some use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Something like...

```
GridView myGV = (GridView)FindControl(myGVstr)
```

Not tested, but might work.

Comment: Could also consider a dictionary with the Checkbox (or checkbox ID) as the key.

Comment: Plausible or possible? Since I am writing it, I have used a very strict naming "standard" so I'm not to worried if you _should_ do it this way or not.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work. I even hard-coded the GridView I'm trying to grab and myGV is still null. Tried changing the FindControl to `(GridView)this.Page.FindControl("gvA1");` and still no dice... was hoping this would work, having to code the same 29 lines 168 times where only the control name changes stinks...

Comment: I've even tried the example from the link you provided and the example doesn't work LOL guess today is Monday part II

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for you help! :)